# Warcraft III, SharpCraft C# plugin: Usage of native "TimerStart"?

Tags: modding

#### about:

[Blizzard Warcraft III](http://eu.blizzard.com/de-de/games/war3/) [furthermore abbreviated as **WC3**]
*related version: WC3: The Frozen Throne 1.26.0.6401 (german Patch 1.26a)*
[MindWorX Sharpcraft](http://www.wc3c.net/showthread.php?t=110643) [furthermore abbreviated as **SC**]
*related version: 1.2.4.0*

#### issue:

I'm trying to use the native "TimerStart" from the **WC3** "common.j" package inside a **SC** plugin written in C#. what gives me problems is the last argument from the native ("code handlerFunc"). as there is no native for creating functions, I dont know how to use it properly, can you give an example? for reference of the "code"-argument (it isnt even declared in the "common.j") i used [Vexorians thread on wc3c.net](http://www.wc3c.net/showthread.php?t=80002), part: "I. The code type". here is the native like declared in "common.j":

```
native TimerStart           takes timer whichTimer, real timeout, boolean periodic, code handlerFunc returns nothing
```

in the **SC** plugin I initialized the native like this:

```
private delegate void TimerStartPrototype(JassTimer whichTimer, JassRealArg timeout, JassBoolean periodic, JassCode handlerFunc);
private static TimerStartPrototype TimerStart = WarcraftIII.Jass.GetNative("TimerStart").ToDelegate<TimerStartPrototype>();
//native TimerStart           takes timer whichTimer, real timeout, boolean periodic, code handlerFunc returns nothing
```

additionally in **SC** plugin, I created a void to pass to the last argument of the native: *(note that "StopCamera" is another native from "common.j" i also initialized in the **SC** plugin but not showing here, because it is done in the same way "TimerStart" was.)*

```
private delegate void StopCameraFuncPrototype();
private void StopCameraFunc() {
    StopCamera();
}
```

usage of the native "TimerStart" in **SC** plugin: *(note that the variable "jTim_mouseWheel" is a "JassTimer" created somewhere else in the **SC** plugin.)*

```
TimerStart(jTim_mouseWheel, (JassRealArg)0.01, false, (JassCode)StopCameraFunc());
```

when im trying to run **WC3** with **SC**, the **SC** console window prints that it couldnt compile the appropriate plugin *.cs-file due to not being able to convert void to JassCode. by simply renaming "void" into "JassCode" I get the error, that not all code paths return a value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JassCode` type is only there as a placeholder, and it doesn't have any actual use right now. The `code` type from JASS is a pointer to a function in a maps compiled JASS script.

I have tried creating new JASS script code at run-time, but I haven't had any good success so far.

Since you're using 1.2.4 there is really no way to achieve what you want. If you were to switch to 2.2.5.124b you'd be able to use the system for attaching C# delegates to a `JassTrigger` with the following code.

```
var trigger = JassTrigger.Create();
trigger.RegisterTimerEvent(0.01f, true);
trigger.AddAction(new DelegateAction((JassTrigger theTrigger) => { 
    /* do stuff here */
}));
```